# Visual FoxPro database, spaces in displayed data

Tags: php, sql, visual-foxpro

I have some problem with removing spaces in my DB response...
i.e data in table is second - `____________________1` by underline I mean spaces... but I can't remove those spaces when I display my data... How can I do it?

I have been tryed `TRIM(), LTRIM(), ALLTRIM(), REPLACE(), STRREPLACE()`, but they are not working with my visual fox pro database...

Can anyone help me with my problem?

**UPD:**
Now I just display with `print_r()` command... but here is some code:

```
$result = odbc_exec($connect, "select
                                        pacienti.pacientid,
                                        pacienti.f_name,
                                        pacienti.s_name,
                                        napravlenie.rtgapparat,
                                        napravlenie.doctor,
                                        opisanie_rtg.opis,
                                        apparatura.prefiks
                                    from
                                        pacienti left outer join napravlenie on pacienti.pacientid = napravlenie.pacientid
                                            left outer join opisanie_rtg on pacienti.pacientid = opisanie_rtg.pacientid
                                                left outer join apparatura on napravlenie.rtgapparat = STUFF(apparatura.gruppa, 0, ' ', '')
                                    where
                                        pacienti.pacientid = '".$pk_full."'") or die ("Error in Database: ".odbc_errormsg());

    $all = array();
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $all[] = $row;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($all);
```

Comment: How are you displaying your data? I assume with PHP, from the tag - in which case, can you add the appropriate code to your question, as well as some sample output?

Comment: @andrewsi see my updates in question

Comment: Have you tried using `trim()` in the PHP code to see if that helps? `trim($all['pacientid'])`, and so on? Does that make a difference?

Comment: @andrewsi nope, it doesnot do anything=(

Comment: In that case, can you try `var_dump($row['pacientid'])` and edit the output into your question? That will show exactly what's in that field when it's retrieved from the database. As Dave Collins says - it's possible they're not really spaces.

Comment: Most of your attempts do not even show up in the [list of available functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710135%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but some do. You don't really show how you use them or how they fail to work. It is possible that you're using them wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try STRTRAN(string_field, ' ','')

Comment: Maybe your "spaces" are not really spaces.  Can you dump the output to a hex editor and look at the actual characters?  You may be getting some ASCII or unicode unprintable characters.  If you can figure out the exact value, you can STRTRAN them out.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Haven't worked in VFP for years, but glad to know I still have some brain cells!

Comment: For future readers, [STRTRAN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978496(v=vs.71).aspx) is VFP's equivalent of **Find & Replace** functionality. This is not the same as trimming and will replace spaces everywhere in the cell value. Use it with caution.

Answer (score 1):

.DBF (dBase/Foxpro table) character fields are padded with spaces so I would recommend that you use `select alltrim(pacienti.f_name) as f_name,...` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: For some reason I'm finding that this removes starting spaces, but not trailing spaces. I think I'm going to have to trim outside of the query instead.

Answer (score 0):

With most database systems these days, you have the luxury of variable width fields. The issue is that the native VFP behavior is to allocate a fixed amount of space for each column in the table. When you execute a SQL statement in VFP, it looks at the first record to determine what the type and size of each field will be, and creates the resulting cursor/table structure accordingly.

For example if you have a table with the first column defined as Char(50), then VFP will allocate 50 spaces (not null characters) in that field so that your string will be exactly 50 characters long on every row.

When you tried to use Select Alltrim(field), ... from table, if the first column of the first record it finds the string "now is the time" then the width of the first column will be 15 characters and all subsequent rows will be padded or trimmed, but all rows will be 15 characters.

You can experiment with this by creating a table of few rows and a single column that contains different amounts of text/white space. then try

> SELECT alltrim(field1)  FROM mytable  ORDER BY len(alltrim(field1)) 
>   INTO CURSOR result

And the result will be that all the rows will only be as wide as the shortest string in the source data.

This means that all your trimming needs to happen after you run your query and cannot be done as part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but i just discovered a way to do it

```
SELECT CAST(columnName as varchar(len(TRIM(columnName)))) FROM table
```

It's not a nice way to write the query but it does appear to crop it correctly.

As mentioned above STRTRAN replaces ALL spaces in the column, so if you have

```
"John Smith    "
```

It becomes

```
"JohnSmith"
```